# сохранение bitmap в android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь сохранить в файл рисунок:

```
public View.OnClickListener drawingsavelistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                drawView.buildDrawingCache(true);
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawView.getDrawingCache());
                File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "test.jpeg");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos);
                    } finally {
                        if (fos != null) fos.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                drawView.destroyDrawingCache();

            }
        };
```

Во время дебага переменная b - наш рисунок - при просмотре выглядит как надо.
Проблема в том что на устройство сохраняется просто черная картинка.
Что делать?

Comment: Насколько я помню, `Bitmap` бывает либо изменяемый, либо нет. Причем изменяемый создается либо через определенный конструктор, либо с помощью копирования в изменяемый `Bitmap`. Возможно дело в этом? Не претендую на правильность, но рассмотрите как вариант

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй поменять

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawView.getDrawingCache());
```

на

```
drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

drawView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
drawView.layout(0, 0, drawView.getMeasuredWidth(), drawView.getMeasuredHeight()); 

drawView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawView.getDrawingCache());
```

Comment: а так вообще вылетает Null pointer exception на строке Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawView.getDrawingCache());